# Ubuntu 12.04 64bit trouble getting wifi to work

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

I'm having a lot of issues trying to get my wlan to work in ubuntu. I have an Atheros AR1111 WB-EG Wireless internal card. I've tried both madwifi and the compat drivers. Neither produced any results. Am I doing something wrong? Or are there cases where neither methods will work?

Must I fall back to ndiswrapper? Wouldn't it be very detrimental to my wifi performance to do that?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot tell you if you are doing something wrong unless you tell us *how* you tried the drivers you tried and what exactly the results were. Was the card detected at all? Could you see wireless networks? What does `iwconfig` show?

In any case, you might want to check out the [ath5k](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/ath5k) driver. The [linuxwireless.org](http://linuxwireless.org) website is a very good source of information.

Finally, no, ndiwrapper should not affect your performance at all. If that is the only way to do it, do so. Last I tried it was relatively easy to set up an worked fine.